# Очистка данных таблицы базы данных Access

Tags: c#, база-данных, ms-access

Мне нужно очистить базу данных. Я делал это так:

```
var dataSet = new DBDataSet();
dataSet.dataTable.Clear();
tableAdapter adapter = new tableAdapter();
adapter.Update(dataSet.dataTable);
dataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

Но БД не очищалась, в ней оставались данные. Как по другому можно произвести очистку БД?

Comment: попробуйте поменять местами dataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges(); и adapter.Update(dataSet.dataTable);

Comment: @AndreiS., к сожалению, не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено, с помощью SQL запроса:

```
DELETE FROM dataTable
```